# Equivalent for match.params in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm converting a React app to Next.js witch i'm new to. I face a problem of getting page numbers for pagination. In my react app i use `this.props.match.params.page` to get the page number, is there a way of using something similar in Next?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add more details to your question with the code. As I understand, you're trying to get page number from query parameter and pass it to some component. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the query params on a client-side with `useRouter` hook.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  console.log(router.query)

  return <div></div>
}
```

[Next Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Comment: I think this only returns named parameters not what i was looking for.
Maybe i'm not use to Next and i'm missed something?

Comment: I guess `router.params.page` is what you want.

Comment: @bcjohn, in Next.js query params are available in `router.query`. `router.params` doesn't exist.